# APK size doubled after Flutter upgrade from 1.5 to 1.7.4?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Why is the size of my app nearly doubled after upgrading Flutter from 1.5 to 1.7.4?

The code is same, however, the APK size increased from `7.6 MB` to `14.2 MB`.
I am using **`flutter build apk`**.

Comment: What command are you using to build the app? 1.7 supports Android App Bundles now, which put both 32 and 64 bit versions of the app into the one bundle file

Comment: flutter build apk -v

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is in response to [this Play Store warning](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31922#issue-439248011).
Flutter now includes *32-bit **and** 64-bit binaries* in APKs built using `flutter build apk` by default which effectively doubles the APK size as it is a fat APK which contains binaries for both ABIs.

There are two ways you can go about reducing your APK size again:

- `flutter build appbundle`

  This option is the preferred way for the Play Store as you are able to upload a single file (that will be `>14 MB` in your case) and the Play Store then builds different APKs for every device from the App Bundle, which means that the **download size** of the APK will be around `7 MB`.
  [Learn more.](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/)
- `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`

  This command will simply output *two different* APK files, one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit, each being about `7 MB`. However, this means that you will have to upload multiple files to the Play Store if you are using that to distribute your application.

[Learn more.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18494#issuecomment-501544474)

Comment: I compared old apk and new arm64 after split abi. Still installed size on device is doubled, blank old apk installed size on device approx 10 MB, new arm64  approx 20 MB.

Comment: That's because new `libapp.so` is always included, which was not there previously